# Erro ao mudar state de checkbox no Reactjs

Tags: javascript, react

Estou aprendendo React ainda na parte de state de um componente. Minha atividade é simples: ao clicar no checkbox o estado do componente CHECKED deve mudar para true e alterar o valor de uma mensagem de texto.
O problema é que ao clicar eu recebo o seguinte erro no console: `TypeError: this is undefined` e nada mais.

Meu código usado segue abaixo:

```
class CheckBox extends React.Component{
    constructor(props){
      super(props);
      this.state = {checked: false};
    }

    changeState(){
      this.setState({
        checked : !this.state.checked
      });
    }

    render(){
      var msg;
      msg = this.state.checked ? 'Sim' : 'Não';
      return(
        <div>
          <input type="checkbox" defaultChecked={this.state.checked} onChange={this.changeState}/>
          <p>{msg}</p>
        </div>
      )
    }
  }

  ReactDOM.render(<CheckBox/>, document.getElementById('app'));
```

Algum mago poderia me indicar o caminho? Desde já agradecido.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você precisa indicar qual é o contexto para `changeState()`, por isso ele diz que `this` é indefinido.

### Solução

```
onChange={this.changeState.bind(this)}
```

O `bind(this)` está passando o component *CheckBox* para o contexto de `changeState()`, dessa forma ele consegue manipular o estado.

---

[PoC](https://jsfiddle.net/3pq1rhq2/)

Outra forma é fazer a ligação do escopo no construtor, dessa forma:

```
constructor(props){
  super(props);
  this.state = {checked: false};

  this.changeState = this.changeState.bind(this); // <--
}
```